# How do I fix OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space?

Tags: java, linked-list, out-of-memory

Hi I need help fixing this OutOfMemoryError for my WordLadder program. Basically I after being halfway through the input wordladder file which contains the start and end words to create the world ladders it slows down significantly and the error occurs. I believe the error is due to the creation of several stacks without removal of already used ones.

The error occurs at Line: 74 in the WordStack file in the getNewStacks method which, as the name says, is supposed to get new stacks.

Below are all the required files:

---

Dictionary txt:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vl6N4-3IYK86lGxmf0hqP7nX2e0BYrim/view?usp=sharing

---

input txt:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ahHBL0ivqhC0zh24DCFnar03hxTt7Awc/view?usp=sharing

---

WordLadder main:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WordLadder {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Dictionary dictionary = new Dictionary(new File("dictionary.txt"));

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            String start = scan.next();
            String stop = scan.next();

            System.out.println(findLadder(start, stop, dictionary));
        }
    }


    static String findLadder(String start, String end, Dictionary dictionary) {

        if (!dictionary.contains(start) || !dictionary.contains(end)) {
            return "No word ladder between \"" + start + "\" and \"" + end + "\".";
        }

        if (start.equals(end)) return start + " " + end;

        LinkedList stackQueue = new LinkedList();

        stackQueue.enqueue(new WordStack(start, end));

        boolean continueSearch;
        boolean success = false;

        WordStack ladder = new WordStack();

        do {
            int queueSize = stackQueue.size();
            continueSearch = false;

            for (int stackIndex = 0; stackIndex < queueSize; stackIndex++) {
                LinkedList newStacks = ((WordStack) stackQueue.dequeue()).getNewStacks(dictionary);
                if (newStacks.size > 0) {
                    while (newStacks.size() > 0) {
                        WordStack next = (WordStack) newStacks.dequeue();
                        if (next.success()) {
                            success = true;
                            ladder = next;
                            break;
                        }
                        stackQueue.enqueue(next);
                    }
                    continueSearch = true;
                }
                if (success) break;
            }
            if (success) break;
        } while (continueSearch);

        if (success) return ladder.toString();
        else return "No word ladder between \"" + start + "\" and \"" + end + "\".";
    }
}
```

---

WordStack (location of error line 74) :

```
public class WordStack {
    LinkedList words;
    String targetWord;
    boolean success;

    WordStack() {
        words = new LinkedList();
        targetWord = "";
        success = false;
    }

    WordStack(LinkedList list, String target) {
        words = list;
        targetWord = target;
        success = false;
    }

    WordStack(String startWord, String target) {
        words = new LinkedList();
        words.push(startWord);
        targetWord = target;
        success = false;
    }

    int size() {
        return words.size();
    }

    void push(String word) {
        words.push(word);
    }

    void add(String word) {
        push(word);
    }

    String pop() {
        if (size() < 1) return null;

        return (String) words.pop();
    }

    String topWord() {
        return (String) words.peek();
    }

    WordStack deepCopy() {
        return new WordStack(words.hardCopy(), targetWord);
    }

    void markSuccess() {
        success = true;
    }

    boolean success() {
        return success;
    }

    boolean contains(String word) {
        WordStack compare = deepCopy();

        while (compare.size() > 0) {
            if (word.equals(compare.pop())) return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    LinkedList getNewStacks(Dictionary dictionary) {
        LinkedList stacks = new LinkedList();

        for (int letterPos = 0; letterPos < topWord().length(); letterPos++) {
            for (char letter = 'a'; letter <= 'z'; letter++) {
                String newWord = topWord().substring(0, letterPos) + letter + topWord().substring(letterPos + 1, topWord().length());
                if (dictionary.contains(newWord) && !contains(newWord)) {
                    WordStack newStack = deepCopy();
                    newStack.push(newWord);

                    if (newWord.equals(targetWord)) newStack.markSuccess();

                    stacks.enqueue(newStack);
                }
            }
        }

        return stacks;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String returnString = "";
        for (int index = size() - 1; index >= 0; index--) {
            returnString += (String) words.getPeek(index) + " ";
        }

        return returnString;
    }
}
```

---

Node class:

```
    public class Node {
       public Object data;
       Node next;

       Node() {
          data = null;
          next = null;
       }

       Node(Object data) {
          this.data = data;
          next = null;
       }

       Object get() {
          return data;
       }

       void set(Object data) {
          this.data = data;
       }

       Node getNextPtr() {
          return next;
       }

       void setNextPtr(Node next) {
          this.next = next;
       }

       public String toString() {
          return "" + data;
       }
    }
```

---

LinkedList:

```
public class LinkedList {
   Node head;
   Node tail;
   int size;


   LinkedList() {
      head = null;
      tail = null;
      size = 0;
   }

   LinkedList hardCopy() {
      LinkedList copy = new LinkedList();
      if(size() < 1) return copy;

      Node current = head;

      while(current.getNextPtr() != null) {
         copy.addEnd(current.get());
         current = current.getNextPtr();
      }

      copy.addEnd(current.get());

      return copy;
   }

   void iterateHead() {
      head = head.getNextPtr();
      size--;
   }

   void addEnd(Object newObj) {
      enqueue(newObj);
   }

   void add(Object newObj) {
      Node newNode = new Node(newObj);

      if(size == 0) {
         head = newNode;
      }

      else {
         newNode.setNextPtr(head);
         head = newNode;
      }

      size++;
   }


   Object peek() {
      return head.get();
   }

   void push(Object newObj) {
      add(newObj);
   }

   void enqueue(Object newObj) {
      Node newNode = new Node(newObj);

      if(size < 1) {
         head = newNode;
         tail = newNode;
      } else {
         tail.setNextPtr(newNode);

         tail = newNode;
      }

      size++;
   }


   Object pop() {
      Node pop = head;

      if(size > 1) {
         head = head.getNextPtr();
         size--;
         return pop.get();
      }

      else if(size == 1) {
         size--;
         head = null;

         return pop.get();
      }

      else return null;
   }

   Object dequeue() {
      if(size < 1) return null;

      Node dequeueNode = head;

      if(size > 1) {
         iterateHead();
      }
      else {
         head = null;
         tail = null;
         size--;
      }

      return dequeueNode.get();
   }


   int size() {
      return size;
   }


   Object getPeek(int index) {
      if(index >= size) return null;

      Node current = head;
      for(int i = 0; i < index; i++) { 
         current = current.getNextPtr();
      }

      Object data = current.get();
      return data;
   }

}
```

---

I do apologize for the amount of required code for the program to run.

Comment: there are lots of examples for how to set java heap size: [here is one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15517399/11374957)

Comment: where would I insert the command?

Comment: you can add it when you run your program, so instead of this: `java WordLadder`, try something like this to run your program with a max heap size of 1024 megabytes: `java -Xmx1024M WordLadder`

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve? For example what are *findLadder* and *getNewStacks* supposed to do in theory? What is the implementation of the class *Dictionary*? Why aren't you using [LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) and probably [Stack](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html)?

Comment: Sorry for possibly overwhelming you with questions but I'm asking because there may be a more efficient way to do this. Maybe. Not sure, but I think it's worth asking.